# DVI -> HDMI pipe sound as well?

Tags: linux, graphics-card, hdmi, dvi

I have a slightly older desktop running Ubuntu Linux with an older Nvidia GeForce 9-series graphics card (with only DVI and VGA output).

I recently got a new HDTV and want to use that as the monitor for this box. Before I run out to get a DVI -> HDMI adapter, I want to know if the audio output can be piped through this as well. I will have no other option for audio.

My only other option is to be a new, relatively cheap graphics card (sub-$100 range) with an HDMI out. Will this be my only other solution?

When I use the integrated video using the HDMI port built into the motherboard, it is at 1080p and works well with the new TV, but the quality is terrible..

Answer (score 0):

You will want to get a new video card.  DVI does not carry sound - (see http://www.geekzone.co.nz/forums.asp?ForumId=34&TopicId=11954)

Comment: Actually some newer graphics cards can output sound through the DVI port (into a DVI-HDMI cable only). Unfortunately, the geforce 9 series cards do not appear to support it. See: http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/57735-6-audio#theMessage389991